Values of variables are not resolving for application file of AzureDevOps agent in AzureDevOps Pipeline
I have defined variables like below in variables/vars-global.yaml file in a project called TEST

This CLUSTER_NAME value I'm able to read it under azure-pipelines.yml file, using the below way:

However, the same variable I'm trying to use it under another directory and file, but it doesn't work, this file is part of Datadog helm chart

I tried different ways to resolve the CLUSTER_NAME' variable value in applications\datadog\dev-gke-cluster` but those are not working, some of those are:

used the relative path of the vars-global.yaml in values.yaml file to use it as a template in values.yaml
added common.yaml in applications\datadog where used the file as a template and imported this common.yaml in values.yaml
Used alternate method of using variables ${{ variables.vmImage }}
I tried multiple other ways to read the variable in values.yaml but none worked.

My intention is when I deploy this project using the AzureDevOps pipeline, I should get a resolved value of $(CLUSTER_NAME) so that I can use this file as an input to Datadog helm chart in ADO Pipeline.
Curretly I'm getting clusterName: $(CLUSTER_NAME) as it is and hence the deployment of helm chart fails for datadog. with below error:

ERROR:

Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed to parse ./applications/datadog/dev-gke-cluster/values.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: invalid map key: map[interface {}]interface {}{"template \"variables.CLUSTER_NAME\" .":interface {}(nil)}
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: execution error at (datadog/templates/daemonset.yaml:118:12): Your `clusterName` isn’t valid. It must be dot-separated tokens where a token start with a lowercase letter followed by lowercase letters, numbers, or hyphens, can only end with a with [a-z0-9] and has to be below 80 chars.

Please note: I have removed redundant information from my files that I took as a screenshot, considering data and code privacy.
How can we pass multiple values of tags section:

Passing single value this way:


$(CLUSTER_NAME) is the macro syntax to reference an Azure pipelines variable, but it has no meaning in Helm charts.
To override values in a Helm chart, use either the --values flag and pass in a file or use the --set or --set-string (to force string values) when using helm install or helm upgrade commands.
Example 1
Considering the following values.yaml file:
datadog:
  clusterName: ""

tags:
  application_name: ""
  customer_name: ""

In a pipeline you can do something like:
variables:
 - template: /variables/vars-global.yaml

steps:
  # other steps here

  - script: >-
      helm upgrade ...
      --set-string datadog.clusterName=$(CLUSTER_NAME)
      --set-string tags.application_name=$(APP_NAME)
      --set-string tags.customer_name=$(CUSTOMER_NAME)
      --install
    displayName: Helm upgrade

Example 2
Considering the following values.yaml file:
datadog:
  clusterName: ""

tags:
  - foo
  - bar

In a pipeline you can do something like:
variables:
 - template: /variables/vars-global.yaml

steps:
  # other steps here

  - script: >-
      helm upgrade ...
      --set-string datadog.clusterName=$(CLUSTER_NAME)
      --set-string tags[0]="application_name=$(APP_NAME)"
      --set-string tags[1]="customer_name=$(CUSTOMER_NAME)"
      --install
    displayName: Helm upgrade


I have added two more screenshots at the end of the original question, I understand the approach for passing a single value, can you please help me know how to pass multiple values like tags (as they are multiple) for the agents, even it's the same case

@Jagdish0886 added more details, but please take a look into the links I posted for more details. Also, you can change script: | to script: >- in order to break down long commands into multiple lines (see How do I break a string in YAML over multiple lines?).

@Jagdish0886 consider using helm upgrade ... --install instead of helm install. See https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/

@Jagdish0886 you don't need to use > symbol in the Helm charts e.g. TAGS: > - I was mentioning YAML multiline strings to break up long commands in the pipeline.

@Jagdish0886 check my 2nd example where tags is defined as an array (each entry starts with a -).
Please pay attention to the symbols in both the values.yaml file and the pipeline such as :, >, - and others.
If you have a fixed number of tags and don't need to iterate over an array, I'd recommend using the configuration from example 1.

can we use the multiline variable TAGS (having all tags together) in vars-global.yaml which can be straightforward injected into the helm upgrade statement  like this --set-string tags=$(TAGS)

@Jagdish0886 you're complicating things. A pipeline variable is a string - you can use --set-string tags=$(TAGS) if the Helm char variable tags is defined as a string as well, not an array. You'll have to parse it somehow in the helm chart. Your choice.

Thank you Rui, I tried to implement Example1, it didnt work since tags expect something like this - application_name:unix which starts with hypen then space, follwed by newline after each tag entry - customer_name:some , I'll give try to Example2 tomorrow, hopefully it should work, tysm

@Jagdish0886 1st example doesn't use an array (i.e. each line with -) - see the values.yaml.
The 2nd example is the one that uses an array, so the syntax is different.

Tysm Rui, the Example2 solution has worked as expected, appreciate help!
